# Google Map is not loading in IOS device in Flutter

Tags: ios, google-maps, flutter, dart

Google Map is not loading in IOS device in flutter, But it's showing properly in **Android device**.
I am using package ***google_maps_flutter 0.5.24+1***

My ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift Code:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
      }
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

  //(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions


}
```

I have changed Info.plist according to docs:

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
        <true/>
```

**NOTE: I HAVE NO RESTRICTION ENABLED IN API**
**And Getting no error in console**

Please give a solution if anyone faces this issues.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is some configuration problem from iOS side,

Please double check iOS configuration from package [readme](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter).

Please make sure that you also have enabled `Maps SDK for iOS` in [Google Developers Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) under `Additional APIs` section.

Comment: Thanks! solved the problem, It was restricted on console, I needed to enable it for IOS.